# Can I use direct I/O in Neo4j?

Tags: java, ubuntu, neo4j, io, read-write

I want to bypass the system's cashing overhead with java using Ubuntu os. How can I use direct I/O? I don't want to use os memory management. My application will be dealing with the storage device/disk directly? The data will not be cashed at all
Any suggestion.